# Create a copy of an ObservableCollection that doesn't update

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I am building a control in xamarin forms that binds to a list of objects. To get this binding to work I need to use observable collections (otherwise propertychanged methods don't fire).

I noticed a really frustrating interaction as a result of needing to use OC's as opposed to lists. Whenever the binded OC updates, the values in my controls are automatically updated, even if they are just references of the OC, Here is how i am copying the OC.

```
//Internal list of events
private List<EventItem> _events;

void OnEventsChanged(ObservableCollection<EventItem> eventsCollection)
{
    //Error handle

    List<EventItem> events = eventsCollection.ToList();

    //Do something

    _events = events;
}
```

The problem comes when the OC updates, I want to check for new/deleted AND altered objects. The issue is that when the OC updates, it is updating the internal list (`_events`) aswell. This means when I go to do comparisons between the old & new values, they are the same.

Honestly I don't really understand how c# handles copying references of objects around, I had a similar issue a while back with `DateTime.Now` being calculated as opposed to copying the value of the already initialised object.

```
var time = DateTime.Now;

await Task.Delay(1000);

var time2 = time; //This is 1 second later than time, not the value of time (which is what I wanted)
```

I have used Objective-C in the past and that has the concept of `MutableCopy` where you can assign a new list from an existing one, they have the same values but aren't linked.

How can I do this in C# so that my controls internal list is only updated by me and not the OC?

Thanks

Comment: `_eventsClone = new ObservableCollection<EventItem>(events);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's perfectly normal. If I have enough time, I'll try to explain it to you.

In a nutshell, the observableList (or a List) is a list of reference to the objects and not a list of objects. The thing is that the objects are not copied inside a list but the list contains a reference to the different objects. That means that if you do something like `ToList()`, you get another list of references to the exact same objects.

Now to solve your problem. Just create a new list with new objects with something like

```
var newList = oldList.Select(x => new Model(x)).ToList();
```

And of course the `Model` class has a constructor that accept a `Model` as a parameter and copy the properties.

Comment: Brilliant, well explained! now my editted events show! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When you write `_events = events;`, you create **not a new** object, but a **reference** for the same object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/index . 
You should to clone (create a copy of object itself) as it mentioned in comment by @Matt.